# Is there a formal name for $(x+1)^3 - x^3 = 3x^2 + 3x + 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

$(x+1)^3 - x^3$ can be simplified to $3x^2 + 3x + 1$. Is there a formal name for this(some theorem)?? Also does this have a relation to geometric progressions since $3x^2, 3x, 1$ is a geometric progression?

Comment: $3x^2, 3x, 1$ is not a geometric progression.

Comment: Are 1, 3x and 3x^2 in geometric progression ?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese. You won by one second ! Cheers.

Comment: Must it be a theorem or have a formal name?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese of course not... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move $x^3$ to the other side, get the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: So foolish of me!

Answer (score 1):

The Binomial Theorem.

$$(x+1)^3=\sum_{k=0}^{3} {3 \choose k}x^k=x^3+3x^2+3x+1$$